# FPDF wrong set_xy and get_string_width

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

The following code should create a PDF using FPDF:

```
font_size = 8

pdf = FPDF(unit = 'mm')
pdf.set_font("Arial", "", font_size)

full_w, full_h = 150, 70

txt = "Text"

txt_w = pdf.get_string_width(txt)
txt_h = font_size * 0.352778 # convert pt to mm

pdf.add_page('P', format=(full_w, full_h))

pdf.set_xy(0, 50)
pdf.cell(txt_w, txt_h, txt, align='R', border = 1)

pdf.output(fname)
```

Strangely, this results in the following PDF:

[image: screenshot of the resulting pdf]

Two problems are there:

1. I place the text at 50mm from the top on a sheet with 70mm height. So why does it not appear at 50mm but on the second page?
2. It also seems that the `txt_w` and `txt_h` are not computed correctly to exactly get the geometric size of the string. How can I get it more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

The text is displayed on the second page because of automatic page break with a margin of 2 cm. Just disable it with `pdf.set_auto_page_break(False)`.